# phpを利用しての、"MySQLのデータベースに接続できない" 原因について

Tags: php, mysql

MAMPを利用して、アプリケーションを開発しています。
当初は、MacOSで実装を進めており、MySQL-Databaseへのアクセスを行うひと通りの処理を、phpで実装していました。
その後、WindowsPCにも、MAMPを導入し、同じスクリプトを適用して、問題ない動作を確認していたのですが、本番で使用するWindowsPCに、MAMPおよび、スクリプトを適用したら、以下の様なエラーが発生し、MySQLのデータベースに接続できない状況が発生しました。

```
Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2003): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061) in C:\MAMP\htdocs\xxxx.php on line 100 エラー::2003
```

同じような状況とその対応方法もネットで見つけ、トライしてみましたが改善が見られない状況です。

不具合の理由と、その対応方法のアドバイスをいただけないでしょうか？
よろしくお願いします。

以下、試してみた対応です。
・ポート番号の変更 (MAMPの設定画面で、Apatch:8888 MySQL:8889 としています。)
・再インストール
・セキュリティソフトのリアルタイムスキャンを一時停止
・サーバーへのログイン →　rootアカウントでアクセスしようとしても、ログイン出来ない状況でした。

サーバー周りの私の知識が浅いため、実際ポート番号の変更に関しては、もしかしたら見当違いの設定をしているかもしれません。

Answer (score 1):

MySQLのサービスが起動していない
→起動しましょう
MySQLがネットワーク接続できるよう設定されていない
→ネットワーク接続できるよう設定しましょう
MySQLがlistenしてるポートとスクリプトで指定しているポートが一致していない
→ポート番号を一致させましょう
Windowsファイヤーウォールでブロックされている
→Windowsファイヤーウォールの設定を追加しましょう